# How can I output the currency symbol in the final exchanged value?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I could output the different currency symbol which the user wants to covert the amount to in my currency converter? For example, if I wanted to convert £20 to euros in the final output of the new amount which was the euro value of £20 how can I get the euro symbol to be outputted? The final output is only numbers and I want a currency symbol in front of the final value amount output and I was wondering how I could do this for every currency for the output amount. I'm importing the live exchange rates from an API therefore, how can I import the exchange rates but add the currency symbol?

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/liamdocherty1/pen/LygEEq)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Fetch exchange rate data from api
$.getJSON("https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=ZAR", function(data) {
  var currencies = [];
  $.each(data.rates, function(currency, rate) {
    // Currency options dropdown menu
    currencies.push("<option id='" + currency.toLowerCase() + "' value='" + rate + "' >" + currency + "</option>");
  });
  $(".currency-list").append(currencies);
})

//Calculate and output the new amount
function exchangeCurrency() {
  var amount = $(".amount").val();
  var rateFrom = $(".currency-list")[0].value;
  var rateTo = $(".currency-list")[1].value;
  if (amount == undefined || rateFrom == "--Select--" || rateTo == "--Select--") {
    $(".results").html("0");
  } else {
    $(".results").html((amount * (rateTo * (1 / rateFrom))).toFixed(2));
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't take much of a [*search*](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=HTML+entities+currency+symbol&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=cSgeWbLfDOzDXvCZgYAC&gws_rd=ssl) to find a list of HTML entities for currency symbols, e.g. [*here*](https://websitebuilders.com/tools/html-codes/currency/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use *toLocaleString* where support for the Intl object is available, you can also use a small lookup table (e.g. `{euro:'&euro;',pound:'&pound;', ...}`) for the symbol and [*format as money*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20format%20money) manually.

```js
/* 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript/149099#149099
decimal_sep: character used as deciaml separtor, it defaults to '.' when omitted
thousands_sep: char used as thousands separator, it defaults to ',' when omitted
*/
Number.prototype.toMoney = function(decimals, decimal_sep, thousands_sep)
{ 
   var n = this,
   c = isNaN(decimals) ? 2 : Math.abs(decimals),
   d = decimal_sep || '.',
   t = (typeof thousands_sep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousands_sep,
   sign = (n < 0) ? '-' : '',
   i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(n).toFixed(c)) + '', 
   j = ((j = i.length) > 3) ? j % 3 : 0; 
   return sign + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : '') + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : ''); 
}

var currencySymbol = {euro:'&euro;',pound:'&pound;',dollar:'$'};

var amount = 123546.23
document.getElementById('moneyAmount0').innerHTML = currencySymbol.euro + amount.toMoney();
document.getElementById('moneyAmount1').innerHTML = currencySymbol.euro + amount.toMoney(2,',','.');
```

```html
<p>Amount (English): <span id="moneyAmount0"></span></p>
<p>Amount (European): <span id="moneyAmount1"></span></p>
```

Note that the result of *toLocaleString* is still largely implementation dependent, and you don't know what it will fall back to if support for options is not available.

The *.toMoney* function is from the highest rated answer to [*How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript/149099#149099)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Localestring

```js
var number = 123456.789;
    
// request a currency format
 console.log(number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));   // → 123.456,79 €


var currency = document.getElementById('currency');

var Euro = number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' });

currency.innerHTML = Euro;
```

```html
<p id='currency'></p>
```

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/646m7905/

Comment: Can't seem to get this working do you have a jsfidde?

Comment: Why post as a fiddle when you can use a runnable snippet here?

Comment: I posted a snippet

Comment: @RobG He didn't have a snippet in his original answer. Why don't you help people instead of being a keyboard warrior?

Comment: @adklkldfadklfaklfdlk—just a simple request. Much easier to access and won't rot like external links have a habit of doing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a way to get the currency name (i.e. "Euros", "Dollars", "Pounds", etc.)? If so, just do this:

```
currencySymbols = {euros:'&euro;',dollars:'$',pounds:'&pound;'};
finalText = currencySymbols[currencyText.toLowerCase()] + currencyValue;
```

That will give you something like `$42` or `£6.38`.